# Disable version check for specific property in Sitecore glass mapper

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore7.1

I'm using `SItecore 7.1` with `Glass.Mapper.Sc 3.1.7.26`. I have the following model, where the `Service Id` field is shared:

```
[SitecoreType]
public class ServiceMapping
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Service Id")]
    public virtual string ServiceId { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following model which references the Service Mapping over a `Droptree` field (also shared):

```
[SitecoreType]
public class OnlineService
{
    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.DisplayName)]
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Service")]
    public virtual ServiceMapping ServiceMapping { get; set; }
}
```

When I load an Instance of `OnlineService` it must be language dependent, due to the `DisplayName`. Let's assume that I have the `OnlineService` available in german and english, and my `ServiceMapping` only in english, then I get `null` for the `ServiceMapping` object when requesting the page in german.

Is it possible to give the `ServiceMapping.ServiceId` property a setting that it should not check for an existing language version? I know that there is the `VersionCountDisabler()`, but I can't use this because I need the `OnlineService` class to check the language version.

Comment: You should look at the [Language Fallback](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Language_Fallback.aspx) modules, this is not a Glass issue.

Comment: @jammykam If this could not be done with Glass (or should not be part of it), why is there the VersionCountDisabler()? This would exactly match my needs, I'm only searching for a way to adapt this for 1 field. Language fallback is a different story. The ServiceMapping item could be there in english or german or whatever. With the fallback, the Item must be there in the fallback language. But I don't need a fallback for shared fields, just would like to disable the version check.

Comment: Ok. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19712345/661447 it may help. I'm sure Mike will be along shortly :)

Comment: @jammykam I just want the points :-)

Comment: @MichaelEdwards Points make prizes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hum, this is a tricky one, the code below isn't tested (I am writing this as I think of the solution) but should point you in the write direction.

```
public class MyCrazyType : SitecoreFieldTypeMapper
{
    public override object GetFieldValue(string fieldValue, Mapper.Sc.Configuration.SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
    {
        using (new VersionCountDisabler())
        {
            return base.GetFieldValue(fieldValue, config, context);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanHandle(Mapper.Configuration.AbstractPropertyConfiguration configuration, Context context)
    {
        //this will mean this handle only works for this type
        return configuration.PropertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof (ServiceMapping);
    }

}
```

Using this Glass will map the an empty item to the target type.

You will need to register the handler with Glass, see this tutorial:
http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial19/tutorial19.html

Comment: Yes, this works perfect. Maybe I will think about creating a custom attribute (inherit from `SitecoreFieldAttribute`) and checking for that attribute in the handler.

Comment: That would give a much more flexible solution! Post a blog if you do, I would like to see it.

Comment: I've written a blog post about this [here](http://ctor.io/shared-field-references-in-glass-mapper/)