# Sitecore Glass.Mapper returns null

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, glass-mapper

Suddenly and for no apparent reason a piece of code using Glass.Mapper that always worked fine no longer does so. I am trying to retrieve the Glass wrapper of the *root element* of my website, which is of template MenuPage:

```
var root = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/ecosystem");
```

this element is not null. But when I try to retrieve the Glass.Mapper version of it:

```
var TreeHead = new SitecoreContext().GetItem<MenuPage>(root.ID.Guid.ToString());
```

This item, that previously was never null, now it is constantly so.

I did read [this question on the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264897/sitecore-glass-mapper-always-null), and indeed when I inspect the root of my website the language seems to be set to "hr" - a value that I never explicitely set, but it's the name of a first-level child of my website that I previously added, and then removed as it was causing problems.

http://screencast.com/t/aMhy7yl3

Could this have somehow made Sitecore/Glass.Mapper think that "hr" (Croatian) should be the language, thus returning a null item? In which case, how do I change the language back to english?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cookies/browser cache, or trying in incognito mode?

Comment: Odd - it works in IE and not in Chrome. Perhaps the system is picking up the language from a Chrome cookie somehow?

Comment: AND IT WAS A LANGUAGE COOKIE,

God knows set from where. Damn. If you add it as the answer I will gladly accept it. Now, how can I configure Sitecore to ignore this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to an incorrect language cookie from your previous visit to "/hr", which Sitecore has interpreted as a request for Croatian. Visit the the page again, even if it does not exists and inspect the cookies and you will see it set as `website#lang=hr` (in Chrome from the resources tab). Even if the language is not set up on your system, the `LanguageResolver` processor in `httpRequestBegin` pipeline will still set that as the Context Language. Since no language version exists for the item, Glass is returning null: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712345/661447

The easiest solution is to clear the cookies to solve the problem for now.

The longer term solution if you want to avoid this completely would require overriding some Sitecore processors, not allowing the language resolver to set the cookie for invalid languages and then throwing a 404 for invalid languages. Some more info here but I think it should go further than what has been discussed: https://sdn.sitecore.net/forum//ShowPost.aspx?PostID=61854

Comment: Haha, glad to have been of help, just one of the random things that has come up this week that I have had issues with myself before :)